# Can someone take a look at my older pending edits. I have one pending since October 13

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have the following edits pending review, with the 2 of them pending for over a month.  I can't retract pending edits and have been restricted from editing anything since Nov 1st. I appreciate the effort invested by all of you and hope that someone can find some time to approve/reject some of my pending edits from October.

| Date | Pending Edit |
| --- | --- |
| Nov 01, 2022 | [Can one read a Twitter feed without account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152906) |
| Oct 30, 2022 | [Select multiple e-mails in Gmail web with only one hand?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152871) |
| Oct 29, 2022 | [Combining TEXT and YEAR returns odd result](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152847) |
| Oct 15, 2022 | [Gmail Boolean query on cc: not working: from:(fname1@fdomain.com OR fname2@fdomain.com) -to:tname@tdomain.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152606) |
| Oct 13, 2022 | [Google Sheets IF Than? question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152571) |

Comment: Just as a curiosity - longest time to approve an edit on [the main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/942627/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval?num=100) and [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.webapps/query/942627/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval?num=100).

Answer (score 4):

The queues have been cleared now.